# Batch Import of json documents to Apache CouchDb

Tags: apache, json, couchdb

I have approximately 250,000 JSON-formatted files, each with one object in it (formatted just how CouchDB likes it with _id).  What's the best way to import these into my remote CouchDB server as records?

-I am on a windows xp machine.

-I have internet access but I can't set up a couchDB server on my local machine and have it be WWW accessible (firewall constraints.) so no easy replication.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would highly suggest that you look into the bulk doc API in the couchdb wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API

Basically, you make a POST request to `/someDatabase/_bulk_docs` that looks like this:

```
{
  "docs": [
    { "_id": "awsdflasdfsadf", "foo": "bar" },
    { "_id": "cczsasdfwuhfas", "bwah": "there" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Just like any other POST request, if you don't include _id properties, couchdb will generate them for you.

You can use this same operation to update a bunch of docs: just include their _rev property. And if you want to delete any of the docs that you are updating, then add a `"_deleted": true` property to the document.

If you have a json file with your documents and use curl, it could look like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @/home/xxx/data.json https://usr:pwd@host:5984/someDatabase/_bulk_docs/
```

Cheers.

Comment: slight correction to Sam's great answer. For deletions, do _deleted : true, not _delete.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I always typo that one. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Newer link to docs: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs